# HTML + CSS Spacing issue when adding content to a widget

Tags: html, css, styling

I'm trying to put together a webpage and am finding that I keep getting white spacing appear when I add content to a widget box.

When I add a H2 in the widgetOne class I'm finding it then pushes the next two widgets down and a white space appears.

I have placed my code on codepen so that it's easier to review:
http://codepen.io/s_bruno1/pen/WRgVVm

```
        <div class="widget widgetOne">
            <h2>Test Heading</h2>
            <a href="">Find out more</a>
            <button>Test</button>
        </div>
```

If anyone is also able to advise how best to code the percentages it will be greatly appreciated. I have attempted this myself but don't feel it's probably the best way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is vertical align is not set. here is the code to make it work

```
.widget {
    min-height: 400px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this has fixed the issue. I appreciate all your kind and helpful responses :)

Comment: I'm glad it did

Answer (score 1):

Your percentages are fine. Try floating your widgets

```
.widgetOne, .widgetTwo, .widgetThree {
    float: left;
{
```

Comment: Float is horrible if you do not know how to use it properly, and can cause all sorts of other white-space issues. Instead use vertical-align: top; Its one-line, solves the issue, and causes less of a headache overall

Comment: Float usually works for me, but any new things I can learn...I appreciate. I'll try it. Thanks.

Comment: At the very least, you should explain why floating fixes it in this case. Trial and error without understanding is not a great way to learn. I have been writing CSS for over 15 years and I don't understand why `float:left` would fix it, I'd love to learn.

Comment: @JuanMendes `float:left` fixes the issue because it collapses the whitespace.  The source of the problem is that inline elements try to align themselves to the initial `vertical-align` value: `baseline`.  In the case of three large `inline-block` elements, that can be a confusing value as you add child elements.  `vertical-align: top;` sets the alignment to be the top line of the `inline-block` elements.  `float:left` just collapses all inline-based whitespace.  Both work, but floating can have unforeseen consequences; whereas `vertical-align` continues to obey "normal" box model positioning.

Comment: @JosephMarikle Thanks, I didn't know about float collapsing white-space

Answer (score 0):

Based on the CSS from the codepen, your widgets have `display:inline-block`.  What's happening is your widgets are trying to adjust their vertical alignment based on the rules of fonts, which factor in vertical alignment, font size, line height, etc. (because that's how inline based elements work).  Try adding `vertical-align: top;` to `.widget`.  This will align all the widgets correctly.

```css
html, body, div, p, ul, li, ol, img, span, a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
}

li {
 display: inline;
 list-style-type: none;
 background-color: red;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.topNavLeft li {
 float: left;
}

.topNavRight li {
 float: right;
}

.subHeading li {
 float: right;
}

.mainHeader {
 padding: 30px;
 background-color: #66d6ea;
 color: white;
}

.mainHeader h1 {
 font-size: 70px;
}

.mainHeader p {
 font-size: 35px;
}

.inner {
 width: 1290px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.widgets {
 width: 102%;
}

.widget {
 min-height: 400px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.widgetOne {
 width: 32%;
 background-color: blue;
}

.widgetTwo {
 width: 32%;
 background-color: green;
 margin-right: 1%;
 margin-left: 1%;
}

.widgetThree {
 width: 32%;
 background-color: orange;
}

.widgetFour {
 width: 48.35%;
 background-color: pink;
 margin-right: 1%;
}

.widgetFive {
 width: 48.35%;
 background-color: silver;
}

.widgetSix {
 width: 59%;
 background-color: gold;
 margin-right: 1%;
}

.widgetSeven {
 width: 37.7%;
 background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Water Choice</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

 <ul class="topNavLeft">
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Business</li>
  <li>Our Company</li>
  <li>News & Media</li>
  <li>Careers</li>
 </ul>

 <ul class="topNavRight">
  <li>Log In</li>
  <li>Register</li>
 </ul>
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
 <div class="inner">

  <ul class="subHeading">
   <li>IMAGE PLACER</li>
   <li>Your account</li>
   <li>Our services</li>
   <li>Your water</li>
   <li>Get help</li>
   <li>Search Icon</li>
  </ul>
  <br>

  <div class="mainHeader">
   <h1>Moving or adding premises</h1>
   <p>Ecerepro ipidebisci de volesequi officimet ilicitibusam sum <br> sam dita qui consedi sinitiincto consequi nate Ceperspi <br> cturio in nossitiatur, ommodis dolorrorit faciistis.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="widgets">
   <div class="widget widgetOne">
                <h2>Test Heading</h2>
                <a href="">Find out more</a>
                <button>Test</button>
   </div><div class="widget widgetTwo">
    <p>Widget Two Placeholder</p>
   </div><div class="widget widgetThree">
    <p>Widget Three Placeholder</p>
   </div><div class="widget widgetFour">
    <p>Widget Four Placeholder</p>
   </div><div class="widget widgetFive">
    <p>Widget Five Placeholder</p>
   </div><div class="widget widgetSix">
    <p>Widget Six Placeholder</p>
   </div><div class="widget widgetSeven">
    <p>Widget Seven Placeholder</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div> <!--inner end-->

</body>
</html>
```